# SVPDynamicPlayer - Adding a red light live button indicator to website from a livestream

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a website: http://www.djkeefer.com/ and in the Broadcasting Live section, I have three videos for live streaming.  I'm trying to add a red light live button to indicate when someone is streaming live and the button would light up red. Any ideas on how to go about this?

This is the code for the first video, The Soulful Experience Show:

```
<div id="svp_player53hd3ih5qv0g"></div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="//play.streamingvideoprovider.com/js/dplayer.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
  var vars = {
    clip_id: "53hd3ih5qv0g",
    transparent: "false",
    pause: "1",
    repeat: "",
    bg_color: "#FFFFFF",
    fs_mode: "2",
    no_controls: "",
    start_img: "1",
    start_volume: "100",
    close_button: "",
    brand_new_window: "1",
    auto_hide: "1",
    stretch_video: "",
    player_align: "NONE",
    offset_x: "",
    offset_y: "",
    player_color_ratio: 0.6,
    skinAlpha: "80",
    colorBase: "#202020",
    colorIcon: "#FFFFFF",
    colorHighlight: "#fcad37",
    direct: "true",
    is_responsive: "true",
    viewers_limit: 0,
    cc_position: "bottom",
    cc_positionOffset: 70,
    cc_multiplier: 0.03,
    cc_textColor: "#ffffff",
    cc_textOutlineColor: "#ffffff",
    cc_bkgColor: "#000000",
    cc_bkgAlpha: 0.7
  };
  var svp_player = new SVPDynamicPlayer("svp_player53hd3ih5qv0g", "", "720", "405", {
    use_div: "svp_player53hd3ih5qv0g",
    skin: "3"
  }, vars);
  svp_player.execute();
</script>
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript! JavaScript is needed to display this video player.</noscript>
<!--player code end-->
```

Comment: To confirm, a video will appear if it's live?

Comment: Right.  As soon as let's say The Soulful Experience show decides to stream live, I need to be able to have a red light appear to show/indicate this.

Comment: Welcome to SO @KevinNowalski - can you please review the following:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Add some context, like what errors you jhave received for example when trying.

Comment: The question: Can you make this video indicate it is live when it goes live via a red light?  Do you recommend any code I could use to accomplish this task?